# Room observable in Kotlin for single db entry

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, observer-pattern

I am using Room for handling db entities and I am adapting the code from the WordRoom example from adroid developers.

I understand that in order to eprform operations that can take a long time I have to use coroutines, and this seems to work fine for inserting and deleting objects into the database. In the main activity I have a recyclerview that onCreate gets binded to its layoutmanager and to the ViewModelProvider.

In the adapter I set an onClick listener to get the current ID of the object in the recycled view>

```
        holder.mealItemView.setOnClickListener {
            (callerContext as MainActivity).getID(current)
    }
```

the getID from the main activity starts a new activity that should retrieve the element from the database and display its properties:

```
fun getID(meal:Meal){
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ActivtyViewMeal::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("mealId", meal.id.toString())
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Then in the ActivityViewMeal in the oncreate I get the intent and  add an observer to the variable that should store the Entity from the database:

```
    mealViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MealViewModel::class.java)
    mealViewModel.aMeal.observe(this, Observer {meal ->
        meal?.let {Log.d(...)
        dataIn.text = it.mealAddDate.toString()})

   mealViewModel.getSingleContentById(mealID.toInt())
```

and after binding the variable with the observer I try to retrieve the data.
My issue is that the log never gets executed.

aMeal is declared inside the ViewModel, a separate kotlin class:

```
class MealViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: MealRepository

    val allMeals: LiveData<List<Meal>>
    var aMeal: LiveData<Meal>
    init {
        val mealsDao = MealRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).mealDao()
        repository = MealRepository(mealsDao)
        allMeals = repository.allMeals
        aMeal = repository.aMeal
    }
    ...
    fun getSingleContentById(id: Int)=viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
         repository.getSingleContentById(id)
    }
}
```

I understand that the coroutine cannot return a value and shall not block.

The meal repository class is defined as follow:

```
/**
 * Abstracted Repository as promoted by the Architecture Guide.
 * https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html
 */
class MealRepository(private val mealDao: MealDao) {
    val allMeals: LiveData<List<Meal>> = mealDao.getAllContentById()
    var aMeal: LiveData<Meal> = mealDao.getSingleContentById(0) //init to avoid null pointer errors
...
    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    fun getSingleContentById(id:Int){
        aMeal = mealDao.getSingleContentById(id)
        // no return from here 
    }
```

and to conclude, getSingleContentById is defined inside the DAO class, that is in another kotlin file.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM meals_table WHERE id=:id")
fun getSingleContentById(id:Int):LiveData<Meal>
```

I have no hint on why I don't get the aMeal updated, while the variable allmeals gets updated correctly.
Any hint would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can change you DB operation to be `suspend` and return `Meal` object:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM meals_table WHERE id=:id")
suspend fun getSingleContentById(id:Int): Meal
```

In your repository make `getSingleContentById` function `suspend` as well:

```
class MealRepository(private val mealDao: MealDao) {

    suspend fun getSingleContentById(id: Int): Meal {
        aMeal = mealDao.getSingleContentById(id)
        return aMeal
    }
}
```

In your `MealViewModel` make `aMeal` of type `MutableLiveData` and update it in `getSingleContentById` function:

```
class MealViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: MealRepository

    val aMeal: MutableLiveData<Meal> = MutableLiveData()
    init {
        val mealsDao = MealRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).mealDao()
        repository = MealRepository(mealsDao)
    }
    
    fun getSingleContentById(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
         val meal = repository.getSingleContentById(id)
         aMeal.postValue(meal)
    }
}
```